# Best and Fastest way to extract Polygon attributes of a Point

Tags: postgis, spatialite, point-in-polygon, oracle-spatial

This is a comparative question, I don't know whether it is allowed to ask this type of Question here or not.

**Problem:** I have a shapefile of almost 1 million polygons with 20-25 attribute fields. I need to extract all the attributes of a polygon that is intersected by a point. In a nutshell, I have a coordinate, I want to get polygon detail where the point (longitude, latitude) falls within. This will be used in a solution (mobile App will call this solution using API) where it will be used very frequently (1000 times in a minute). So, as the usage is high I need to figure out the best, most efficient, fastest and less resource consumption solution.

**Probable Solution:** What kind of solution currently do I have?

**1. PostgreSQL & PostGIS:** Using PostGIS `ST_Within` I can easily get the solution. But It is wise to get an RDBMS solution for such a high-usage application?

**2. Oracle Spatial:** Same goes for Oracle Spatial as PostgreSQL. Using `SDO_Within` or `SDO_Inside` or `SDO_Toches` the polygon info can be found but is it worthy to use oracle RDBMS for such use?

**3. SpatiaLite:** I can convert shapefile to SpatiaLite format then I can call it using SQLite query. Is it faster than RDBMS system?

**4. GeoJSON Format**: Converting shapefile to GeoJSON will return a too-large JSON file. Polygon info can also be extracted using a few libraries. But is this solution worthy and faster?

**5. Other Solution using R or Python:** As per a few online documents I came to know that few libraries of R and Python can do similar things without the help of any RDBMS. These are file-based solutions using the different formats of GIS data.

What will be the best approach for my application which does not resource-hungry but efficient and faster?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: @IanTurton, Thanks for your generous comment. Actually, I know 2-3 solutions already. But I wanted to know and compare all the solutions. How can I compare or get an expert opinion if I post questions separately?

Comment: I would simply go for 1. and yes it is fine to do so. It will probably also be the fastest of all options (Oracle probably similar)

Comment: The only way to get all those answers is to implement all those solutions and benchmark the results. Or you can pick one, implement it, and choose/test an alternative if it seems slow. Any way you roll it, you're asking us to predict how efficiently you'll implement each solution, and to compare the outcomes with undefined data -- That's too hypothetical for our Focused question/Best answer model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the data format is important in this case. Once it's loaded in memory, it doesn't change much, only the initial loading time of your service.
To be really efficient in this case, I think you should focus on two things:

- The data needs to be loaded in memory, and eventually shared memory if you use several thread (to avoid duplicates)
- You need index to search your correspondance, and more specifically spatial index (classical index will not work)

The advantage of a solution like Postgis or Oracle is that they already handle themself multi-thread, shared memory, cache and keeping data on disk if not needed (to optimize memory usage if you don't have much), and search with spatial index (according that it's properly configured and that you create index).

With other solutions, often index are the problem, so when you do an intersection they will try to intersect with all the polygons. Also, if your data does not fit in memory it's a whole new problem, you need to load and unload your data from disk when needed, handle cache invalidation and whatnot, ...

**My advice would definitely be a postgis**:

- It's free, more reliable and simpler to manage and evolve than a script. For example if in the future you want to update your data without a service interruption, or add a lot of data and you can't keep everything in memory anymore, or this kind of things, it would be a lot more easy.
- It's definitly fast (at least when configured properly) and will be able to handle way more than your expected performance (way [biggest services](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2022/06/postgis-logos.html) than that run on postgres).
- You can find managed solution if you want to be able to start with a small server and increase size seamlessly at will. There is even cluster of postgres (citus, postgres-xl, ...) if you really have millions of users in the future.

**Note:**

Here is also other ideas to increase performance:

- if your data is not projected, you can project it, search will be simpler and faster in 2D than with GPS data on a spheroid. With a solution like postgis, I'm not not if it will make a big difference in the end because it's optimized and quite fast, but if you want to use a script it's definitly something to do.
- maybe a raster approach can be faster in your case ? If your data in concentrated enough, and you can allow a small imprecision of putting your data in a grid, you can make a raster with the id of the polygon, and keep all your fields in another table for example. I'm not sure if it's quicker if you use postgis (my guess is that it's not worth the trouble), but I think I would try to look in this direction if I wanted to try the script solution (it's more simple than to handle index).